# Get the mode value of a column based on another column's value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe read from a csv file,

```
>>> df
                                song                        artist  year  \
0                        (Iwas)BornToCry                          Dion  1962
1      (LastNight)IDidn'tGetToSleepAtAll               The5thDimension  1972
2             (Sittin'On)TheDockOfTheBay                   OtisRedding  1968
3        (You'reSoSquare)Baby,IDon'tCare                  JoniMitchell  1982
4                                  20-75                WillieMitchell  1964
5                 50WaysToLeaveYourLover                     PaulSimon  1976
6                                 Abacab                       Genesis  1982
7                  Abraham,MartinAndJohn                          Dion  1968
8                        AbsolutelyRight         FiveManElectricalBand  1971
9               ACowboy'sWorkIsNeverDone                    Sonny&Cher  1972
10                        AddictedtoLove                  RobertPalmer  1986
11                   ADreamGoesOnForever                  ToddRundgren  1974
12                   AfterTheLoveHasGone               Earth,Wind&Fire  1979
13                        AftertheLovin'          EngelbertHumperdinck  1977
14                        AgainstTheWind                      BobSeger  1980
15                    AHazyShadeOfWinter              SimonAndGarfunel  1966
16                       Ain'tNoSunshine                   BillWithers  1971
17                    Ain'tTooProudToBeg                TheTemptations  1966
18                       ALessoninLeavin                    DottieWest  1980
19                            AliveAgain                       Chicago  1978
20                           AllAloneAmI                     BrendaLee  1962
21                     AllIEverNeedIsYou                    Sonny&Cher  1971
22                         Allshewantsis                    DuranDuran  1989
23                           AllThisTime                         Sting  1991
24                    AllThroughTheNight                   CyndiLauper  1984
25                   AlmostbyBeingInLove                MichaelJohnson  1978
26                           AlmostGrown                    ChuckBerry  1959
27                      AlongComesAWoman                       Chicago  1985
28                             ALoveSong                    AnneMurray  1974
29                           AlreadyGone                     TheEagles  1974
..                                   ...                           ...   ...
700                           WildHorses                 RollingStones  1971
701                 WillieAndTheHandJive                   EricClapton  1974
702                         WillieNelson                BlueEyesCryin'  1975
703                   WillTheWolfSurvive                      LosLobos  1985
704                WillYouLoveMeTomorrow                  TheShirelles  1961
705                 WishSomeoneWouldCare                    IrmaThomas  1964
706         WithALittleHelpFromMyFriends                     JoeCocker  1968
707                      WithaLittleLuck                 PaulMcCartney  1978
708                     WithOrWithoutYou                            U2  1987
709                  WithYouI'mBornAgain                  BillyPreston  1979
710                         WomanToWoman                  ShirleyBrown  1975
711       WonderfulWorld,BeautifulPeople                    JimmyCliff  1969
712                        WorldInMyEyes                   DepecheMode  1990
713                           WorriedGuy               JohnnyTillotson  1964
714        WouldItMakeAnyDifferenceToYou                     EttaJames  1963
715                             YearsAgo                GeorgeHarrison  1981
716                         YearsFromNow                       Dr.Hook  1980
717  You'reTheFirst,TheLast,MyEverything                    BarryWhite  1974
718                     You'vegotaFriend  RobertaFlackandDonnyHathaway  1971
719          You'veGotAnotherThingComin'                   JudasPriest  1982
720         YouCan'tJudgeABookByTheCover                     BoDiddley  1962
721    YouCan'tRollerSkateInABuffaloHerd                   RogerMiller  1966
722                       YouCanCallMeAl                     PaulSimon  1986
723                   YouDecoratedMyLife                   KennyRogers  1980
724                        YouDon'tOwnMe                    LesleyGore  1964
725             YouMakeMeFeelLikeDancing                      LeoSayer  1977
726                   YoungHeartsRunFree                   CandiStaton  1976
727            YourLoveHasLiftedMeHigher                  RitaCoolidge  1977
728     YouTookTheWordsRightOutOfMyMouth                      MeatLoaf  1978
729                        YvonneElliman               IfICan'tHaveYou  1978

      c1   c2   c3   c4   c5   c6   c7   c8   c9   c10   c11   c12   c13  \
0    1.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   3.0   1.0   4.0   8.0
1    1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  4.0  5.0  2.0  8.0  2.0   7.0   6.0   8.0  13.0
2    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0  2.0  6.0  4.0  9.0   8.0   9.0   2.0  12.0
3    1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   1.0   1.0   4.0  10.0
4    1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  5.0   2.0  11.0   7.0  11.0
5    1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   3.0   1.0   4.0   8.0
6    1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0  4.0  3.0  1.0  7.0   6.0   8.0   1.0   7.0
7    1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  6.0  8.0   5.0   7.0   9.0   2.0
8    1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  5.0   2.0  11.0   7.0  11.0
9    1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   3.0  10.0  11.0   9.0
10   1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  4.0  2.0  3.0   9.0   3.0  10.0   3.0
11   1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  10.0   2.0   5.0   5.0
12   1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  4.0  5.0  2.0  8.0  2.0   9.0   3.0   8.0   3.0
13   1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  10.0   2.0   5.0   5.0
14   1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  6.0  8.0   5.0   7.0   9.0   2.0
15   1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  5.0  4.0  3.0  1.0  7.0   6.0   8.0   1.0   7.0
16   1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  6.0  8.0   5.0  10.0   9.0   2.0
17   1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  4.0  2.0  3.0   1.0   4.0   3.0  10.0
18   1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  4.0  5.0  2.0  8.0  2.0   7.0   6.0   8.0  13.0
19   1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   3.0   5.0   6.0   3.0
20   1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  5.0   2.0  11.0   7.0  11.0
21   1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  10.0   2.0   5.0   5.0
22   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0  4.0  6.0  4.0  9.0   6.0   4.0   2.0  12.0
23   1.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   3.0   1.0   4.0   8.0
24   1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  8.0  5.0   2.0  11.0   7.0  11.0
25   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0  4.0  3.0  1.0  7.0   6.0   8.0   1.0   4.0
26   1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  6.0  8.0   5.0   7.0   9.0   2.0
27   1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  4.0  5.0  2.0  8.0  2.0   7.0  10.0  11.0   9.0
28   1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  5.0   2.0  11.0   7.0  11.0
29   1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  6.0  8.0   5.0   7.0   9.0   2.0
..   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
700  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  6.0  8.0   5.0   7.0   9.0   2.0
701  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   3.0   1.0   4.0   8.0
702  1.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   3.0   1.0   4.0   8.0
703  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  6.0  8.0   5.0   7.0   9.0   2.0
704  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  4.0  5.0  2.0  8.0  2.0   7.0   6.0   8.0  13.0
705  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  4.0  5.0  2.0  8.0  2.0   7.0   6.0   8.0  13.0
706  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  5.0   9.0   3.0  10.0   3.0
707  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  4.0  2.0  3.0   1.0   4.0   3.0  10.0
708  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  6.0  8.0   5.0  10.0  11.0   9.0
709  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  5.0   2.0  11.0   7.0  11.0
710  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0  4.0  6.0  4.0  9.0   6.0   4.0   2.0  12.0
711  1.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   3.0   1.0   4.0   8.0
712  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  4.0  2.0  3.0   1.0   4.0   3.0  10.0
713  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  4.0  5.0  2.0  8.0  2.0   7.0   6.0   8.0  13.0
714  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  4.0  5.0  2.0  7.0  1.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   6.0
715  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  10.0   2.0   5.0   5.0
716  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  5.0   2.0  11.0  11.0  11.0
717  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  10.0   2.0   5.0   5.0
718  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  10.0   2.0   5.0   5.0
719  1.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   9.0   3.0  12.0   1.0
720  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  6.0  8.0   5.0   7.0   9.0   2.0
721  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  5.0   2.0  11.0   7.0  11.0
722  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  4.0  5.0  2.0  7.0  1.0   4.0  10.0  11.0   9.0
723  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  7.0  6.0  8.0   5.0   7.0   9.0   2.0
724  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  4.0  5.0  2.0  8.0  2.0   7.0   6.0   8.0  13.0
725  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  10.0   2.0   5.0   5.0
726  1.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  3.0  6.0   3.0   1.0   4.0   8.0
727  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0  2.0  6.0  4.0  9.0   8.0   9.0   2.0  12.0
728  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  7.0  6.0   3.0   5.0   6.0   6.0
729  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  6.0  4.0  2.0  3.0   9.0   3.0  10.0   3.0

      c14   c15
0     8.0   7.0
1     6.0   1.0
2     1.0   3.0
3    11.0  15.0
4     4.0  10.0
5     8.0   7.0
6    10.0   8.0
7     3.0   2.0
8     4.0  10.0
9    14.0  12.0
10    7.0   6.0
11    9.0   4.0
12    7.0   6.0
13   13.0   4.0
14    5.0   2.0
15   10.0   8.0
16    3.0   8.0
17   11.0  15.0
18    5.0   1.0
19   14.0   6.0
20    4.0  10.0
21    9.0   4.0
22   14.0   5.0  
23    8.0   7.0
24    4.0  10.0
25   10.0   9.0
26    3.0   2.0
27    5.0  12.0
28    4.0  10.0
29    3.0   2.0
..    ...   ...
700   3.0   2.0
701   8.0  11.0
702   8.0   7.0
703   3.0   2.0
704   6.0   1.0
705   6.0   1.0
706   7.0   6.0
707  11.0  15.0
708   3.0   7.0
709   4.0  10.0
710  14.0   5.0
711   8.0   7.0
712  11.0  15.0
713   6.0   1.0
714  12.0  11.0
715  13.0  14.0
716   4.0  12.0
717   9.0   4.0
718   9.0   4.0
719   2.0  13.0
720   3.0   2.0
721   4.0  10.0
722  14.0  12.0
723   5.0   2.0
724   6.0   1.0
725  13.0  14.0
726   8.0   7.0
727   1.0   3.0
728   5.0  11.0
729   7.0   6.0
```

What I want to be able to find is the most common value in column 'c15' for any  value in 'year'. What would be even better is a small table of the most common values in c15 for any given year.

I know this seems simple enough, but I can't seem to find a solution online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and apply the `value_counts` function to extract the most common `c15` value within each group:

```
df.groupby('year').apply(lambda x: x['c15'].value_counts().idxmax())
```

The output of the above is a Series of most common `c15` values indexed by year.

Comment: Excellent, this worked, thank you! The difference between this answer and something I tried before (which didn't work) is the idxmax() part.